# Dynamic variable in Jenkins pipeline with configFileProvider

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to replace the the DB cred based on the env name in Jenkins, but I am unable to achieve the same.

I have a JSON Config Files like this named '*JsonConfig*'

```json
{
  "production": {
    "DB_USERNAME": "userABC"
  },
  "development": {
    "DB_USERNAME": "userXYZ"
  }
}
```

and this what I have in `Jenkinsfile`

```
def getEnvName() {
    if ("master".equals(env.BRANCH_NAME)) {
        return "production";
    }
    return env.BRANCH_NAME;
}

def config;

node(){
    configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'secret-credentials', targetLocation: 'JsonConfig')]) {
        config = readJSON file: 'JsonConfig'
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Setup") {

            when {
                beforeAgent true
                anyOf { branch 'master', branch 'development' }
            }

            steps {
                sh """
                sed -i 's#__DB_USERNAME__#config.${getEnvName()}.DB_USERNAME#' ./secret-data.yml
                cat ./secret-data.yml
                """

                //Alternative 
                sh "sed -i 's#__DB_USERNAME__#${config.getEnvName().DB_USERNAME}#' ./secret-data.yml"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I statically pass the var name like this, then it is working fine.

```
sh "sed -i 's#__DB_USERNAME__#${config.production.DB_USERNAME}#' ./k8s/secret-data.yml"
```

I want to make "production" dynamic so that it reads the value which is returned from `getEnvName()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic line is

```
sh """
    sed -i 's#__DB_USERNAME__#config.${getEnvName()}.DB_USERNAME#' ./secret-data.yml
"""
```

This will evaluate as the shell command

```
sed -i 's#__DB_USERNAME__#config.production.DB_USERNAME#' ./secret-data.yml
```

But you want to be evaluated to

```
sed -i 's#__DB_USERNAME__#userABC#' ./secret-data.yml
```

Since the `config` is a Groovy object representing the parsed JSON file we can access its properties dynamically using the subscript operator (`[]`):

```
sh """
    sed -i 's#__DB_USERNAME__#${config[getEnvName()].DB_USERNAME}#' ./secret-data.yml
"""
```

Comment: Hi @marcin-kłopotek thanks for your answer, but after using the mentioned code it is throwing this error `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: config for class: groovy.lang.Binding`. I think it is unable to access `config` var.

Comment: Are you able to access the `config`  in your original solution? Please provide the source code of the modified pipeline to get more context about the error mentioned.

Comment: I made a typo at that time, that is why it was throwing error. Now it is working. Thank you!